# inhomogeneous coordinates to homogeneous coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, curves, mathematical-modeling, spline

I will appreciate your help to solve this question.
 For a function $fi:R^2 → R$  in inhomogeneous coordinates, we obtain a function 
$fh : R^2$ × ($R$ \ {0}) $→ R$ in homogeneous coordinates as: 
$fh(x, y, w) := fi(\frac xw, \frac yw)$. 
**Prove that**:
(1) If  $ fi(x, y) = 0$  is a bivariate polynomial equation, then $fh(x, y, w) = 0$ is a trivariate polynomial
equation such that all monomials have the same degree.

(2) The equation $fi(x, y) = 0$ has at least one solution if and only if $fh(x, y, w) = 0$ 
**Has infinitely many solutions**.

Comment: Please check the way $f_h$ is defiend. As is, it's false: if you take $f_i(x,y)=x^2+y+1$, $f_h(x,y,w)=x^2w^2+yw+1$ is certainly not homogeneous.